# Site design update

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, Web Applications community site got a slight design update today. I have moved site's CSS to a newly refactor LESS system, so it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally going on forward. Also I've updated site's logo and icons to SVG for retina support.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old CSS bugs. If you see any new ones, or old ones not being fixed, please let me know!

Comment: So much white space... total waste of my monitor size. Do you guys realize some use SE with a computer?

Comment: I for one like the new style.

Comment: [meta-tag:notifications] should be about the notifications that Stack Exchange presents to users. I've updated the tag wiki to reflect this. If this question needs another tag, it would probably be `announcements`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are accessibility bugs:

- Text with too low contrast in the list of questions. It's worse on Stack Overflow on a Nexus 5 screen (although on mobile I usually use the Android app), less serious on WA.
  *Please increase contrast* for those of us with less than ideal vision, using platforms and monitors with various gamma curves and settings, and reading mobile screens in bright daylight.
- Text that's too small to read without eyestrain, e.g. user names and tab names ("Questions", "Tags", ...) on Stack Overflow on a Nexus 5 screen. Again, WA is better but you said you're working on the CSS across the SE network.
  *Please do text sizing in `sp` units or at least `pt` units,* never in `px` units.

Answer (score 2):

New design looks pretty nice, more 'flatter', and the button shave some depth.

The off-topic vote to close pane fonts seem to be bit bigger than the rest of the page - is this intentional?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can we please reinstate the white space height WA had in comparison to what we have now?

See MSO question: [meta.stackexchange.com/q/194616/205469](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194616/205469)